# Can I disable \setminted for a code?

Tags: minted, code, javascript

in order to apply a minted style globally and not to copy paste these styles in every **`\begin{minted}`** I will use in my paper, I am using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{minted}
% global minted style  
\setminted{  
frame=lines,  
framesep=2mm,  
baselinestretch=1.2,  
fontsize=\footnotesize,  
linenos,  
breaklines  
}  

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{TypeScript}  
code here  
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

so my question is if is it possible to disable these **`\setminted`** styles for some **`\begin{minted}`**?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  it will be easier for someone to help you if you expand your example to be compilable -- begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can override options with the optional argument to `\begin{minted}`. But that might be a pain if you have many code blocks you want to override. Or you could use `\setminted[lang]{...}` if the different styles apply to different languages. Or you could use `\newminted` to create a new environment that does what you want. Would any of those options suit your use case?

Comment: @DavidPurton With \setminted[lang]{...} it would be different styles for different languages tho, so it's the same problem for that specific lang's style later.
For changing between styles I have to use `\newcommand{\mintedstyleone}{\setminted{...}}` and another `\newcommand{\mintedstyletwo}{\setminted{...}}` I guess..

Comment: I don't think using two `\newcommand` will work since the two `\setminted` commands will be cumulative. From my reading of the `minted` manual and source, I think using `\newminted` might work best. I'll post an answer and you can see what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `\newminted{TypeScript}{...}` and then `\begin{TypeScriptcode}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{TypeScript}{
  frame=lines,
  framesep=2mm,
  baselinestretch=1.2,
  fontsize=\footnotesize,
  linenos,
  breaklines
}  
\begin{document}
\begin{TypeScriptcode}
code here  
\end{TypeScriptcode}
\begin{minted}{TypeScript}
code here  
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this should be the better practice to do it I think :)